# Spark Scala Dataframe Transform of Nested Maps into a Single Dataframe Row?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to write a nested data structure that transforms a dataframe consisting nested Maps and simple values into a single dataframe row wrapped in an array.

The result should transform this dataframe:

```
+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value        |records                                                                                                                                                                        |
+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|123          |[USA -> [1475600496 -> 25.000000000000000000], ITA -> [1475600500 -> 18.000000000000000000, 1475600516 -> 19.000000000000000000], JPN -> [1475600508 -> 27.000000000000000000]]|
|256          |[USA -> [1475600508 -> 40.000000000000000000, 1475600500 -> 47.000000000000000000], NOR -> [1475600496 -> 30.000000000000000000]]                                              |
|118          |[USA -> [1475600500 -> 50.000000000000000000]]                                                                                                                                 |
+-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

into:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|valueAndRecords                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[123, [USA -> [1475600496 -> 25.000000000000000000], ITA -> [1475600500 -> 18.000000000000000000, 1475600516 -> 19.000000000000000000], JPN -> [1475600508 -> 27.000000000000000000]], [256, [USA -> [1475600508 -> 40.000000000000000000, 1475600500 -> 47.000000000000000000], NOR -> [1475600496 -> 30.000000000000000000]]], [118, [USA -> [1475600500 -> 50.000000000000000000]]]]|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I can combine both columns into a single struct with the line below but it doesn't wrap the results in an array.  How can this be completed?

```scala
df.withColumn("valueAndRecords", struct("value", "records")).select("valueAndRecords")
```

Comment: do you have a key column in your input dataframe? or do you want all the rows in DF to become just one row?

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve and what the current error is. Are there errors?

Comment: @C.S.ReddyGadipally, I do have the same key for the three rows in dataframe, however, my example did not provide that step :P.  @Shu provided an answer using `collect_list` inside `agg()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your **`struct`** inside **`array`** i.e `array(struct(...))`

```
df.withColumn("valueAndRecords", array(struct("value", "records"))).select("valueAndRecords")
```

**(or)**

Using **`collect_list:`**

```
//sample data PS I don't have all data for records column
df.show(false)
//+-----+----------------------------------------------+
//|value|records                                       |
//+-----+----------------------------------------------+
//|123  |[USA -> [1475600496 -> 25.000000000000000000]]|
//|256  |[USA -> [1475600508 -> 40.000000000000000000]]|
//|256  |[USA -> [1475600500 -> 50.000000000000000000]]|
//+-----+----------------------------------------------+

df.groupBy(lit("1")).agg(colle_list(struct("value", "records")).alias("valueAndRecords")).select("valueAndRecords").show()

//+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|valueAndRecords                                                                                                                                                      |
//+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|[[123, [USA -> [1475600496 -> 25.000000000000000000]]], [256, [USA -> [1475600508 -> 40.000000000000000000]]], [256, [USA -> [1475600500 -> 50.000000000000000000]]]]|
//+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you @Shu.  Yes, `collect_list` inside of `agg()` worked like this: `df.agg(collect_list(col("valueAndRecords")) as "valueAndRecords")`